# submit R script to grid in form of batch

Tags: r, grid-computing

I wanted to submit a R job to the grid. I have saved the main R code in `MGSA_rand.r`
In the file `callmgsa.r` I have written

```
print('here')
source('/home/users/pegah/MGSA_rand.r')
mgsalooprand($SGE_TASK_ID,382)
```

And I use the file `Rscript.sh` to call the job (with the `-t` parameter I send the value corrseponding to `$SGE_TASK_ID)`

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save callmgsa.r
```

I submit the job like this:

```
qsub -t 1 -cwd -b y -l  vf=1000m /home/users/pegah/Rscript.sh
```

I neither get an error nor any output. The job terminates just as I submit it, with out any output. Could you please help me?
thanks, Pegah

Comment: Have you tried Rscript as a shebang? That's the usual way for creating scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750786/whats-the-best-way-to-use-r-scripts-on-the-command-line

Comment: If $SGE_TASK_ID is an environment variable, you need to use `Sys.getenv("SGE_TASK_ID")` to access it within your R script.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$SGE_TASK_ID` is a shelscript variable. Calling it in R with the same syntax is no going to work. What you could do is use `Rscript` in stead. From the shellscript you call:

```
Rscript callmgsa.r $SGE_TASK_ID
```

In the R script you can catch the command line arguments like:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
print('here')
source('/home/users/pegah/MGSA_rand.r')
mgsalooprand(args[1],382)
```

This should work...

Comment: thanks for your answer. But where should I call the R itself? I have called it in Rscript.sh.

Comment: You call R using Rscript through the shellscript.

Comment: ... or put a shebang at the top of your callmgsa.r, something like `#!/path_to_R_install/bin/Rscript` and make the file an executable `chmod +x callmgsa.r`.