# Create and execute an R script just like perl -e to script R in a shell such as bash?

Tags: perl, r, bash

I tend to use perl -e option to add Perl scripts in a shell script such as bash without creating a Perl script file.

```
perl -e '
while (<>) {
  print; 
}' < file
```

Is there a similar way of doing this for R? I want to write R scripts in a bash script but without creating an R script file.

One way is to use

```
R --vanilla <<RSCRIPT
a <- "hello\n"
cat(a)
RSCRIPT
```

Unlike perl -e, when using $, one has to prepend a backslash when to refer to a column of a table. In perl -e, we do not need to use \$ to refer to a perl variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is. You can use `Rscript`:

```
Rscript -e 'print("hello world")'
```

Comment: I am embarrassed by the answer. So, I can use -e option with Rscript. Thank you!

Comment: But, I could not run the following script, Rscript -e '                                                                       
a <- "hello"                                           
print(a)                                                                     
' so I think -e does not seem to be the solution that I am looking for.

Comment: `Rscript -e ' a <- "hello"; print(a) '`

Comment: I think that another possibility is found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750786/whats-the-best-way-to-use-r-scripts-on-the-command-line

Comment: -e doesn't work with multiple line inputs, unlike the perl version. I get "ARGUMENT 'print(a)' __ignored__" if I hit return between assign and print...