# How can a script find itself in R running from the command line?

Tags: r, shell, command-line

I have a script (call it `Main.R`) that has the following code to find itself when I run it:

```
frame_files <- lapply(sys.frames(), function(x) x$ofile)
frame_files <- Filter(Negate(is.null), frame_files) 
main.dir <- dirname(dirname(frame_files[[length(frame_files)]]))
```

This is used to get the directory above its own directory, `main.dir`, which is used to call other scripts relative to this path.

I'm interested in running this script from a command line, for example

```
R CMD BATCH Main.R
```

or

```
Rscript Main.R
```

Unfortunately, the commands above do not work when I call the script from the command line.

Is there any code I could put in `Main.R` or a call option to `R` or `Rscript` that I can use instead?

More specifically, the solution would need to work in Windows.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750786/whats-the-best-way-to-use-r-scripts-on-the-command-line

Comment: To be fair, I'm not sure, but it doesn't look like it. I have to say, I'm not great at using the command line. I've edited my post to add that I'm using Windows, I don't know if it makes a difference in the answer. Reading some other posts, I get the impression #! doesn't work in Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is a solution that will give you the correct file directory path when the script is run either with `source` or with Rscript.

```
# this is wrapped in a tryCatch. The first expression works when source executes, the
# second expression works when R CMD does it.
full.fpath <- tryCatch(normalizePath(parent.frame(2)$ofile),  # works when using source
               error=function(e) # works when using R CMD
                     normalizePath(unlist(strsplit(commandArgs()[grep('^--file=', commandArgs())], '='))[2]))
dirname(full.fpath)
```

The key to this is the function `normalizePath`. Given a relative or abbreviated path name, `normalizePath` will return a valid path or raise an error. When running the script from Rscript, if you give `normalizePath` the base filename of the current script, it'll return the fullpath, regardless of what your current directory is. It even gets the path right when you supply a relative path to R CMD and there's a script with the same name in the current directory!

In the code above, I extract the filename from one of the strings returned by `commandArgs`. If you take a look at the output of `commandArgs`, you'll see that the filename is the 4th argument. The argument is recorded as '--file=yourscript.R', so in the final line above, I split the string on '=' and pull out the file name.

Comment: +1 - but run `Rscript` with extra options, like `--vanilla` and `--file=[...]` could end up anywhere. It would be wiser to use a `grep` like function to find it rather than use a hardcoded position like `4`.

Comment: Thanks for drawing attention to this. Left it out for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @mplourde Thanks! I was not aware of `normalizePath`. I like that you got it all in there with `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 1):

On idea is to give the path as an argument to your Main.R

I Suppose You call it with RScript.

```
Rscript Main.R 'path'
```

in your Main.R you add the code to read the argument

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
mainpath <- as.character(args[1])
```