# Full filename of the currently sourced file

Tags: r

In many (interpreted) programming languages, a variable is set when sourcing a file so that some code can determine the filename from where it is loaded. E.g. in ruby, the variable `__FILE__` is set when loading a file.

Is there such a feature in R? Is there a way for R code to determine from where it is loaded?

Example:

main.R:

```
source("foo.R")
```

/home/bar/foo.R:

```
print(FULL_FILENAME)
```

What do I have to replace FULL_FILENAME with to make it print:

```
[1] "/home/bar/foo.R"
```

without hardcoding any filenames in the source?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, I found the following alternative approach: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/FILE-for-R-td919451.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hack [provided by Gabor](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-January/184745.html) a while back by putting this on top of your file :

```
this.file <- parent.frame(2)$ofile
```

If you want to extract the name of the directory, you can do :

```
this.dir <- dirname(this.file)
```

From my understanding of things, sourcing a file creates two parent environments. The outer one (two steps up) contains the information about the file from where the code is sourced.

Comment: Thanks. I added normalizePath() to it to get the full filename.

Comment: @lith normally that shouldn't be necessary, unless you want to use "/" on Windows.

Comment: This will work when the script is run with `source`, but not when executed using `RScript`. See my answer here for the general solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477852/how-can-a-script-find-itself-in-r-running-from-the-command-line/13480153#13480153

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more reliable way to do this that doesn't depend on the implementation of `source`:

```
(function() {
    print(getSrcFilename(sys.call(sys.nframe())))
})()
```

Comment: No `print` and `{…}` necessary, making this *slightly* simpler: `(function() getSrcFilename(sys.call(sys.nframe())))()`

Comment: This does not work for me, I get: `> sys.nframe()` returns
`0`, 
`> sys.call(sys.nframe())` returns `NULL` and
`> getSrcFilename(sys.call(sys.nframe()))` returns
`character(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that I've found uses `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()` and `sub()`

- Work for both .Rmd and .R file when working interactively.
- Works when sourcing .R script files
- Works when knitting .Rmd files

```
    current_file <-
      rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path %>% 
      sub(".*/", "", .)
```

The `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path` returns the full path of the current file, while the `sub(".*/", "", .)` extracts everything after the last `/` from the full fle path, leaving only the name of the file.