# Running R Scripts on a server?

Tags: r, cran

I would like to install R on a server (linux) where I could create shell scripts to execute R scripts on the server. Does R support this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't it? For example you can find [R as a webapp](http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/) or [R Studio over ssh](http://www.r-bloggers.com/rstudio-server-through-ssh/) as more complex examples or just login via ssh and use R.

Comment: I'm a little unsure as to which Linux install to use on my server and how to execute R Scripts from within the command line.

Comment: Linux distros for servers are a matter of taste. I usually go with debian but you can use whatever you are used too (if you are new to linux I think debian and ubuntu have the most guides on server setup). R over commandline can be found in this question for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line

Comment: So I have to install a Linux distro on my server and then install R along with it?

Comment: Yep if u rent a server (virtual or full) it usually comes with a distro of your choice pre installed. If you build it yourself you would have to install it yourself. Installing R should be easy. For debian it's just  `apt-get install r-base` and an additional `apt-get install` for the additional packages see http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/

Comment: Thank you so Trudbert! I appreciate your patience :)