# How to run an R script file from the command line

Tags: r, command-line, rscript

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this issue but I've tried everything and I think I just don't understand how the command line works in windows. I have a file saved in a folder on my desktop, let's say:

```
C:\Users\abika_000\Desktop\R models\myfile.R
```

Here is the directory to my R/bin or Rscript/bin:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin
```

I want to run this code using the cmd prompt. How would I go about doing this?

I've tried this solution from the question below but I just keep getting errors no matter what I do:

[Run R script from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line)

What I entered:

```
> R CMD BATCH C:\Users\abika_000\Desktop\R models\myfile.R
> Rscript C:\Users\abika_000\Desktop\R models\myfile.R
```

The errors I get are:

```
'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

EDIT::

Credit to splendour and Phil. I wound up fixing it by entering:

```
> "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\"R CMD BATCH "C:\Users\abika_000\Desktop\R models\myfile.R"
```

I apologize for the poor question. I just wasn't sure how to use the cmd prompt /directories in trying to use R CMD BATCH or Rscript

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Usually you would use `R CMD BATCH \path\to\script\script.R`. What have you tried, and what errors do you see?

Comment: edited question with trials and errors. most of what i've tried is useless and simply not what cmd line is looking for

Comment: You need to add the R/bin folder to your Path environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think step 1, if you haven't already done it, is to use a UNIX-y shell emulator, such as [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).
Then, assuming it's available on Windows (as it is on Linux/OSX), you can use the wrapper program [`Rscript`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html).

Or, if you have a UNIX-y shell emulator, you can always pipe input straight into `R`, e.g.:

```
R --no-save --no-restore < your_script.R
```

Answer (score 2):

The executables for `R` have not been added to your environmental variable `PATH`. The error you are receiving is CMD complaining that it cannot recognize `R` as an executable.
Both `R` and `Rscript` exists under Windows.

From the CMD, write

echo %PATH%

Did you see the path where R is install there? Probably not.

Where is R installed? I'm guessing something like `C:\Program Files (x64)\R\R-3.1.2`

Follow this link for adding a path to `PATH`: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

The path you want to add is *not* the location where R is installed, but a subdir. Either add `C:\Program Files (x64)\R\R-3.1.2\bin` or `C:\Program Files (x64)\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64`.

Restart a command prompt, and try to start `R` from the command line (just type `R`).