# create R script files, Saving as R script file and opening R script file from command line

Tags: r, command-line

I am using R from a distant linux server. I want to make an R script file, open an scripts files and edit them. However, I can just use the R command line. I have no idea how I can create an R script file like in RGui, or how to open such files for editing.

Comment: Why do you want to edit a script with R? Use an text editor such as vi.

Comment: No, it is bunch of R functions, needed to be ran several ties. It must be in ***.R file.

Comment: If you have access to R, you have access to the terminal. Create a file (using your local text editor, like nano, or vim and pass that to Rscript or run it manually through R.

Comment: Alternatively create your script on your local computer and send it to the server. That's what I did before we installed RStudio Server. It's often more convenient than working in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple non graphical editors to edit your file that you have access to in command line, like `nano` or `vim`.

To create an Rscript file, simply add `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` at the top of your `.R` file and make it executable.

Also see [Run R script from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line)