# cmd or bat run commands within file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This might be very basic but I cannot find the answer in the internet.

I have a cmd/bat file with 3 basics lines to set the working directory as the one of the current folder.Once I run it, I get the CMD window, and I type specific commands (example : "start notepad").

```
%~d1
cd "%~p1"
call cmd
```

What should I write within the cmd. or bat. file so the "start notepad" will be already launched as command?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want cmd and notepad to be opened at the same time?

Comment: Yes, as an example.
I also use R (which is correctly configured in path) from cmd. So I have to type manually R and press Enter. I would like to avoid that kind of "typing"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
Command.Com
```

When you'll open this batch file it will open up CMD where you can start typing commands like start notepad etc...I think this was what you was looking for?

Comment: He can already open cmd from a batch file. He wants to open a different program.

Comment: What do you think the `Command.Com` is? `'command.com' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this.
You can open notepad directly with the `start` command and then run cmd, like this:

```
@echo off
%~d1
cd "%~p1"
start "" notepad
call cmd
```

You can also include the notepad start command directly in the cmd call, like this:

```
@echo off
%~d1
cd "%~p1"
call cmd /k start "" notepad
```

Note that there is a `""` after `start` because `start` considers the first set of quotes that it encounters to be the window's title.

Comment: Almost there.
Actually the %~d1 cd "%~p1" is useless.

Would like to the same for a basic R code.

call cmd /k R

now I want automatically the second line which after running R will run automatically source("myfile.R")

How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much

Comment: @Arkadiw - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line