# how to run a r program written in a file with .r extention?

Tags: r

I have a file that have some R program code i.e. `progm.r`, kept it on my desktop: `C:\Users\sandeeptiw\Desktop\progm.r`.

I have set the variable path like: `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\`

Now, how can I run this program ?

Comment: https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line

Comment: Or something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line/18306656#18306656

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\Rscript.exe C:\Users\sandeeptiw\Desktop\progm.r`

should sort you