# How to add R code in an HTML page

Tags: html, r, integration

I am creating a Twitter sentimental analysis and in the html page, I am giving a tab for looking at the Word Cloud. The Word Cloud code is in R. How do I integrate the R code into my HTML page. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use any server side languages like php and execute your R code with php shell_exec function and return this data to html using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Either call an external R-script from php or whatever language you are using (see: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line)) , and generate the images and html-code to be included with knitr or something similar.

Or try Rstudios `shiny` package to serve this part of the site directly from R.