# R equivalent to `python -i`

Tags: python, r, command-line, interactive

Typing `python -i file.py` at the command line runs `file.py` and then drops into the python terminal preserving the run environment.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Is there an equivalent in R?

Answer (score 2):

I may be misinterpreting what `python -i file.py` does, but try:

From inside R, at the terminal, you can do:

```
source('file.R')
```

and it will run `file.R`, with the global environment reflecting what was done in `file.R`

If you're trying to run from the command line, review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line)

Comment: Yes, the idea is from the command line. Thanks for the link. Very useful to see the variety of ways to run an R script at the terminal. Still haven't found one that drops you into the R terminal afterwards, at least I don't see it in the man pages. If you haven't used it, do try `python -i`. I find it indispensable for debugging scripts.

Comment: What advantage is there to running the script in such a way that it opens python and puts you into the environment (via `python -i`), as compared to opening R and `source()`ing the file? Aside from the 2 seconds lost due to having to manually open R ;)

I use Rmarkdown to do all my reports/analyses/etc so I knit my documents from inside RStudio

Comment: That is a good point. There is no simple equivalent to `source()` in Python, which is what makes `-i` very handy. Can't off the top of my head think of an example where `source` wouldn't fit the bill.