# R script with user input from command line

Tags: r

I cannot find a solution to this particular problem, even though more or less similar questions have been questioned before in:

- [Run R script from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line)
- http://www.cureffi.org/2014/01/15/running-r-batch-mode-linux/

Running a script from bash is easy enough, however once one needs user interaction I couldn't find a solution. Please consider the example:

```
userInput<-function(question) {
  n = 0
  while(n < 1 ){
    n <- readline(question)
    n <- ifelse(grepl("\\D",n),-1,as.integer(n))
    if(is.na(n)){break}  # breaks when hit enter
  }
  return(n)
}

investedLow<- userInput("Invested value in low risk since last time: ")
```

Now if I save this script as `test.R` and run it for `R --no-save < teste.R` the entire script is run and the time for user input does not happen.

The script works fine in Rstudio, for example.

- How to wait for user input in a script to be run in the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a total hack, repurposing a very specific purpose-built package for your more-general question:

```
library(getPass)
userInput<-function(question) {
    n = 0
    while(n < 1 ){
        n <- getPass::getPass(msg = question)
        n <- ifelse(grepl("\\D",n),-1,as.integer(n))
        if(is.na(n)){break}  # breaks when hit enter
    }
    return(n)
}

investedLow <- userInput("Invested value in low risk since last time: ")
print(investedLow)
```

Maybe the worst part about this is that `getPass` hides the user input. There must be a way to modify the source code to fix that.

**Update:** The getPass [author pointed out](https://github.com/wrathematics/getPass/issues/13#issuecomment-359838527) that the solution could be as simple as using `readLines` slightly differently:

```
cat(question)
readLines(file("stdin"), n=1)
```