# Running R file to render bookdown output from command line (Terminal)

Tags: r, terminal, bookdown

I'm trying to run an R file from the command line (from Terminal -- on macOS 10.13.3).

Following the directions in [this helpful Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line), I added `#! [path/to/file.R]` as the first line of the R file.

When I then type `Rscript [path/to/file.R]` in Terminal, a part of the file to test that it worked seems to run (I added a `print()` statement), however, the next line:

`rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_book', encoding = 'UTF-8')`

Leads to this error:

```
Error in rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book",  : 
  No site generator found.
```

Why does the `print()` statement appear to work fine, but this line - to render a **bookdown** book - does not?

The file I'm trying to run is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/jrosen48/dissertation/blob/master/render.R).

Answer (score 3):

For *Markdown* I have had the following [script](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/render.r) in the examples directory of [littler](https://cran.r-project.org/package=littler) for about 1 1/2 years, and rendered hundreds of times with it.

Note it calls `rmarkdown::render()` yet you want a bookdown format, so methinks you may need to write a very similar script calling `bookdown::render_book()` or a similar function.

You can of course do exactly the same as a one-liner from Makefiles, and many people do. Here is one which will map all Rmd file to pdf documents (which is my standard workflow, I don't do much html):

```
sources :=              $(wildcard *.Rmd)
slides :=               $(sources:.Rmd=.pdf)

all:                    ${slides}

%.pdf:                  %.Rmd
                        Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render(\"$<\", clean=TRUE)"
```

Because my editor has a shortcut for invoking `make` this is particularly handy.

Lastly, for Rscript (available everyhere) you'd do `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` or possibly the direct path to `Rscript`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple script like this that you save to `compile.book.sh` for example.

```
#!/bin/sh

## Get the path to the book
BOOK_PATH=$1

## Get the current path
CURRENT_PATH=$(pwd)

## Get to the right path
cd ${BOOK_PATH}

## Compile the book
R -e 'rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_book', encoding = 'UTF-8')'

## Get back to the previous path
cd ${CURRENT_PATH}
```

You can then execute the compilation as follows from wherever in your machine (from the terminal):

```
sh compile.book.sh path/to/Rfolder
```

With `path/to/Rfolder` being the folder where your `index.Rmd` is.