# how to run all R code in console with one click?

Tags: r

I want to make a generic script in which user can run all my r code in console with single click

My some R code

> nil_sal_log_sqldf = sqldf("Select psno, name , unit , DOS, Field_description , log_new_value , 
>   MAX (inserted_on) as INSERTED_ON  from test group by psno having log_new_value = 'Yes' ")

and many more code like this

Right now user have to copy my code and run it on console

is there any way that he can run my whole code with singe click

Comment: Click? In console you type, there is no clicking if I am not mistaken

Comment: What editor are you using ? The classical Rgui ?

Comment: R studio, using console

Comment: is there any way like we use in shell script, put all your code in script and then save file and then run the file. 
is there anything like this in R

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: [*Run R script from command line*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line) ?

Comment: Are you using Rstudio? Because if you are sharing your .Rmd file, there is a button for doing just what you want to accomplish. But if you want to save the R code in your markdown file into an R script, you can try `knitr::purl`.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + G in RStudio will prompt for a source code file which is then executed using `source(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working in R Studio, you should probably be able to click "File" -> "New File" -> "R Script". That should open a separate window in which you can type all your code, and you can save that script and run it at a later time after reopening.

For example you could use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to run all code in the script from beginning until the current line.