# Run a R script on a remote machine

Tags: r, remote-server

I have a local and a remote machine. I would like to let a R script run on my remote machine. Since it is computationally expensive, it will take quite some time.

How can I execute a command/script on the remote server, such that it continues the computation even after detaching?

My operating system on the remote server is Ubuntu 16. I use a ssh connection.

Comment: I won't mark duplicate, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line) seems to be what you want here.  Please search SO before posting a question.

Comment: Thank you for your input Tim. But the question is how to let it run even after detaching.

Comment: Then see the answer below.  You may use a Windows scheduled task.  This doesn't really have much to do with R per se.

Comment: Please add some more system details - operating system, method of remote connection etc etc.

Comment: What's the operating system on your remote machine? A solution with Linux is to use `screen` and then start your script as usual with `Rscript file.R`. You can change back to the terminal window with `ctrl+a+d`, see list of screens with `screen -ls` and get back to your running script with `screen -r <id>`.

Comment: If you run the script from the command line with `RScript` you can use `disown` and/or `nohup` or commands like that to let it run after logging off

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a batch file in the remote desktop machine and if you want it to run on  fixed time you can use Task scheduler feature in Windows to schedule the batch file.