# Single line code to run R code from Windows command line

Tags: r, windows, cmd

I Want a single line code to run a shiny app from windows command line without opening the R application.

If I open the R from cmd and run the code it works.
But it gives error for the following single line code.

```
R -e 'shiny::runApp(system.file("examples/01_hello", package="shiny"), launch.browser = T)'

............
............
> 'shiny::runApp(system.file(examples/01_hello,
+
+ Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted
```

Please help. Thanks..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line

Comment: It looks as though you need to escape the quotes in your command string.  The `shQuote()` function in R includes several ways to do that.  Read the help page carefully to choose which type of escaping to do.

Comment: @JonnyPhelps I have already gone through the link.. Other simple code like        r -e "cat(getwd(),'\n')"       works.. but the code I am using gives error.....

Comment: It doesn't work if you put your code in a .r file and use the Rscript command? Have you set up the environment variables for R?

Comment: @user2554330 .. Copy Paste the code... Does not worked

Comment: @JonnyPhelps     RScript TestRScript.R     also works.. It's mean environment variables for R is Ok ....???

Comment: Yeah should be, you can check by following these instructions, but adapt path to where your version of R is installed. http://yizhexu.com/2017/02/r-path/

Comment: @RajaSaha: yes, escaping for the cmd shell is hard.  I'd use Jonny's suggestion:  put your code in a file and run that.

Comment: @JonnyPhelps I don't have admin access to change the env path.. I think if there was a path setup problem then    R -e "cat(getwd(),'\n')"   also would not worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working:

```
RScript -e "shiny::runApp(system.file('examples/01_hello', package='shiny'), launch.browser = T)"
```

I have made two changes:

1. Replace R by RScript
2. Interchange single and double quotes

Comment: single quote doesn't work for me on Windows 10; double quote does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, in Windows command prompt, single quote doesn't work for this case.

```
R -e "shiny::runApp(system.file("'examples/01_hello'", package="'shiny'"), launch.browser = T)"
```

Comment: Not working.. Output: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.'

Comment: @RajaSaha Updated my original answer, seems like in windows command prompt, the quotes are nightmares. I tried R -e "cat(getwd(), "'\n'")" and it works on my windiws

Answer (score 0):

You can try in cmd something like this (for example)

```
> "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.0\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" ".\app.R"
```

Inside app.R i have, so it is runs shiny app

```
shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = server,
  options = list(launch.browser = T))
```