# Rscript behaves inconsistently on windows with single and double quotes

Tags: r, windows, powershell

If I invoke

```
Rscript -e "print('hello')"
```

It correctly prints out the answer

```
[1] "hello"
```

However, if I switch single and double quotes, it does not work, and it looks like the double quotes are removed:

```
Rscript -e 'print("hello")'
```

gives:

```
Error in print(hello) : object 'hello' not found
Execution halted
```

Note that it's not powershell doing the escaping incorrectly. Echoing only gives the expected results:

```
PS> echo 'print("hello")'
print("hello")
PS> echo "print('hello')"
print('hello')
```

And the same behavior is not observed on macOs or Linux, where both variants are correctly parsed.

Interestingly enough, it's even crazier for command.com:

```
C:>Rscript -e "print('hello')"
[1] "hello"

C:>Rscript -e 'print("hello")'
[1] "print(hello)"
```

I mean... what?!?
This has already been mentioned here:

[Single line code to run R code from Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145275/single-line-code-to-run-r-code-from-windows-command-line/54291514#54291514)

but there's no explanation about it. In my opinion it's a bug of Rscript on windows, but I want to hear other opinions.

Comment: Does explicitly escaping the quotes with backslashes fix it?

Comment: @AllanCameron yes it does, but it's really an odd behavior which makes little sense, especially because it's only happening on windows.

Comment: Is the `rscript` command an executable or a script?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart If I remember correctly it's an exe file.

Comment: I suggest trying [`getargs`](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/getargs) to see the actual command line that PowerShell is passing to the command.

Comment: @StefanoBorini where are you running rscript from? cmd?

Comment: May be in windows anything between double and single quotation is considered as a string! so, the (hello) will be considered as another object or variable that does not exist!
#Difference Implementation between Linux base and Windows base of R compiler

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/q/51080215/3358272: *"CMD doesn't treat single quotes as anything but a regular character"*, I'll infer same/similar to powershell. (This doesn't perfectly explain it, but I think many assume either R's behavior (single or double quotes are relatively interchangeable) or shell behavior (double quotes allow variable expansion, single quotes don't, but both book-end strings), but `cmd.exe` is different enough.

Comment: Windows doesn't use backslash for escaping, so it means the escaping is performed in rscript.

Answer (score 13):

[Dabombber's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63609686/45375) provides all the pointers, but let me try to boil it down conceptually:

The problem is not specific to `RScript.exe` and potentially affects calls to *any* external executable from PowerShell:

**Up to at least PowerShell 7.1** (current as of this writing), **passing arguments with *embedded double quotes (`"`)* to *external programs* is fundamentally broken**, as detailed in [GitHub issue #1995](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995); in short: behind the scenes, PowerShell constructs a command line for the target program (process) that uses `"..."`-quoting only, but neglects to *escape* embedded *verbatim* `"` chars. for their syntactically valid inclusion in such double-quoted strings; **a fix may be coming in v7.2** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

- For now, you have to *manually escape embedded `"` chars. as `\"`*.
- However, if and when the bug gets fixed, this workaround will *break*, because the fix requires that this escaping be applied *automatically*, which would then escape a verbatim `\"` as `\\\"`.

```
# WORKAROUND as of v7.0, which will break if and when the problem gets fixed.
PS> Rscript -e 'print(\"hello\")'
```

The third-party **[`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native)** (install with `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser Native`, for instance) offers **helper function `ie`**, which **compensates for the broken behavior**; it is written in a forward-compatible manner so that it will simply defer to the built-in behavior if and when it should get fixed:

```
# Thanks to `ie`, no workarounds are required.
PS> ie Rscript -e 'print("hello")'
```

As for ***ad hoc* workarounds** - both of them work for `Rscript.exe`, but can't be expected to be a *general* solution:

- For target programs that support both `'...'` and `"..."` quoting: Swap the quotes to use only embedded `'` chars., as shown in your question, but note that `'...'` and `"..."` strings have different semantics in PowerShell (`"..."` strings are [expandable (interpolating) strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)), and may have different semantics in the target program too (not the case in `Rscript`):

  - `Rscript -e "print('hello')"`
- For target programs that accept input *via stdin*, use the PowerShell *pipeline*, where the bug doesn't surface (though note that you may have to set the `$OutputEncoding` preference variable to the character encoding expected by the target program):

  - `'print("hello")' | Rscript -`

---

As for your observations and **background information**, including about `cmd.exe` and POSIX-compatible shells:

> Note that it's not powershell doing the escaping incorrectly.

As Dabombber points out, it *is* PowerShell that is the problem, but the problem only occurs when calling *external programs*, whereas `echo` is a built-in *alias* for the PowerShell-native
`Write-Output` *cmdlet* (verify with `Get-Command echo`).
On Windows, you could see the problem with the flawed parameter passing as follows, by invoking `choice.exe` (ignore the  `[Y,N]?N` suffix):

```
PS> 'n' | choice /m 'print("hello")'
print(hello) [Y,N]?N
```

`choice.exe` with `/m` can be used to echo an argument as it would be received by external programs, and as you can see the double quotes were effectively *lost*, because PowerShell mistakenly placed `print("hello")` *verbatim* on the process command line - without *escaping* the `"` chars. - which external programs parse as verbatim `print(hello)`, because they allow a single argument to be composed of unquoted and double-quoted parts (`print(` + `hello` (stripped of the syntactic double quotes) + `)`).

- If verbatim `print(hello)` is interpreted as an R script, it looks for a *variable* (object) named `hello` - which in this scenario doesn't exist and triggers the error message you saw.

On Unix-like platforms (macOS, Linux), using the cross-platform [PowerShell [Core] edition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell), `/bin/echo 'print("hello")'` shows the same problem.

> And the same behavior is not observed on macOs or Linux, where both variants are correctly parsed.

Yes, if you use a *native*, POSIX-compatible shell there, such as `bash`, you'll get the correct behavior (see below).

> it's even crazier for command.com:

As an aside: You probably meant [`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), the legacy command processor (Command Prompt) on NT-based Windows platforms up to the current Windows 10.
([`command.com`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMAND.COM) was the command processor on the extinct DOS-based Windows versions that ended with Windows ME).

**`cmd.exe`** only recognizes *double*-quoting (`"..."`) to demarcate argument boundaries for *itself*, not also single-quoting (`'...'`); irrespective of that, it essentially *passes the original quoting through*  to the target executable (after performing its own interpretation of the command line, such as environment-variable expansion).

This differs fundamentally from what PowerShell and POSIX-compatible shells do:

- On Unix-like platforms - where POSIX-compatible shells recognize `'...'`-quoted arguments - the concept of a *process* command line doesn't exist, and whatever arguments a POSIX-like shell has itself parsed out of its command line are passed *as-is* - as an *array* of verbatim arguments - to the target executable; thus shell string literals `"print('hello')"` and `'print("hello")'` are passed as *verbatim* `print('hello')` and `print("hello")`, respectively, which works as expected, given that R too recognizes both `'...'` and `"..."` string literals.
- PowerShell too has `'...'` strings (it treats their content verbatim), but on Windows it *translates them to `"..."` strings* behind the scenes (if quoting is needed), which is where the aforementioned bug can surface  as of v7.0. The bug aside, this translation makes sense, because only `"..."` quoting can be assumed to have syntactic meaning *on the command line* for other programs (see bottom section). Unfortunately, PowerShell does the same thing on Unix-like platforms, even though it shouldn't (it constructs a *pseudo* command line that the .NET API then parses into an array of verbatim arguments passed to the target process), so the bug surfaces there as well.

Because `cmd.exe` preserves the original quoting, `RScript` interprets `'print("hello")'` in command line `Rscript -e 'print("hello")'` as a *string literal* rather than as a *command*, because it removes any `"` chars. with *syntactic* function on the *command line* first (whereas `'` (single quotes) by convention do *not* have syntactic meaning on the command line), *before* the result is interpreted as an R script:

- `'print("hello")'` is therefore parsed as `'print(` + `hello` (the command-line `"` are stripped) + `)`, resulting in verbatim `'print(hello)'` getting interpreted as R code, which is an R *string literal* that therefore prints as-is (the output uses `"..."` quoting, but that's just an artifact of output formatting; note that an explicit call to `print()` isn't necessary, the result of an expression - such as string literal `'print(hello)'` in this case -  is *automatically* printed).
- By contrast, `"print('hello')"` is parsed as verbatim `print('hello')` (the command-line `"` are stripped), which - due to the absence of enclosing quoting - is then interpreted as a *command*, namely a `print()` function call, as intended.

---

Ultimately, there are no hard and fast rules in the anarchic world of process command-line parsing **on Windows: it is ultimately up to each program to interpret its command line** - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094897/45375) contains excellent background information.

Fortunately, however, **there are widely adhered-to conventions**, as implemented in the MS C/C++/.NET compilers and [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019#parsing-c-command-line-arguments).

Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.0, PowerShell doesn't adhere to these conventions, due to the aforementioned bug. Since the bug has been around since v1, users have learned to work around it, such as with *manual* `\"`-escaping, as shown above. The problem is that fixing the bug would *break* all workarounds. Implementing a fix as an [experimental feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_experimental_features) is now being considered, for v7.1 at the earliest - see [this PR on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/13482) and the associated discussion [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995#issuecomment-678685215), which suggests that, in addition to implementing the widely established conventions, accommodations be made for calls to *batch files* and `msiexec.exe`-style programs, which have non-conventional quoting requirements.

Answer (score 9):

It might be worth taking a look through this PowerShell issue: [Arguments for external executables aren't correctly escaped](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995). The [Native module by Michael Klement](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) provides a workaround until the problem is fixed (and shouldn't be broken post-fix like many current workarounds).

> Note that it's not powershell doing the escaping incorrectly. Echoing only gives the expected results

`echo` is a PowerShell function rather than an external program so you won't notice the broken behaviour when using it.

```bsh
PS> Get-Command echo

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           echo -> Write-Output
```

A better test would be to use the EchoArgs.exe command line tool from [PowerShell
Community Extensions](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=pscx) (downloadable [here](https://github.com/AnthonyMastrean/chocolateypackages/tree/master/packages/echoargs/tools)).

```bsh
PS> echoargs.exe 'print("hello")'
Arg 0 is <print(hello)>

Command line:
"E:\echoargs.exe"  print("hello")

PS> echoargs.exe "print('hello')"
Arg 0 is <print('hello')>

Command line:
"E:\echoargs.exe"  print('hello')
```

Answer (score 3):

> Note that it's not powershell doing the escaping incorrectly. Echoing
> only gives the expected results:

In the case of using echo, its echo which is directly consuming the argument you are passing to it, so you get the same result for single quotes or double quotes.

In the case of Rscript, I believe Rscript is just a convenient way of calling R with some additional arguments. (see https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/05-cmdline/ for explanation). Specifically, it says that "From this output, we learn that Rscript is just a convenience command for running R scripts...."

So maybe what's happening is that when you call RScript, its passing the argument to a separate process, and because of this its trying to expand hello as a variable, leading to the error (in the Powershell case)

As for cmd it has its own behavior for handling single and double quotes.

See: [What does single-quoting do in Windows batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173825/what-does-single-quote-do-in-windows-batch-files)
and
[Differences between single and double quotes in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080215/differences-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-cmd/51090074)

So the problem may not be with RScript. The resulting output of your use case may just be a side effect of how powershell and cmd handle double quotes and single quotes.

This may also explain why the problem is there only on windows, and not in Linux or MacOS.

Comment: I've undone the down-vote again and I'll leave it at that. I still find "[...] and because of this its trying to expand hello as a variable, leading to the error (in the Powershell case)"  confusing: yes, `hello` is being interpreted as a variable - but the root cause is _PowerShell's broken argument-passing_ (`print("hello")` rather than `print(\"hello\")` is placed on the process command line, causing `Rscript.exe` to parse it as verbatim `print(hello)` before executing it as R code).

Answer (score -1):

Check out this one! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7

1. expressions in single-quoted strings are not evaluated. They are interpreted as literals.
2. in a double-quoted string, expressions are evaluated, and the result is inserted in the string.
3. same rules apply for cmd

Comment: Yes, `'print("hello")'` is a literal (verbatim) PowerShell string resulting in verbatim `print("hello")`, but since there's nothing to interpolate in `"print('hello')"`, it is effectively also a literal string, resulting in verbatim `print('hello')` - both verbatim strings _should_ result in the same `RScript` output _if effectively passed as such_. That the results differ implies that there must be a problem with PowerShell's argument passing, which is what the question is about. No, the same rules do _not_ apply to `cmd`, which has no concept of single-quoted strings.