# RScript cannot handle spaces in "-e" argument if invoked via Start-Process from Powershell

Tags: r, powershell

I want to invoke some R-Code by a certain `Rscript.exe` via a `Start-Process`-cmdlet. To do this, a powershell variable is given as `-e` argument to Rscript in order to evaluate the code.

### Steps to reproduce

Assuming the Powershell is opened in the `bin`-Folder of a R-Installation, I can pass code as argument:

```
$code = "print('Nospaces');Sys.sleep(12)"
Start-Process .\Rscript.exe -ArgumentList "-e", $code
```

**But** if the code contains any spaces whatsoever, the Rscript will fire an `unexpected end of input`-Error:

```
$code = "print('With spaces');Sys.sleep(12)"
Start-Process .\Rscript.exe -ArgumentList "-e", $code #it does not matter if code is in parenthesis or not
Start-Process .\Rscript.exe -ArgumentList "-e", "$code"
```

In this example, the space is located within a print statement, but hte space can be set anywhere within the code.

It does however work, if I do not invoke Rscript.exe via `Start-Process`:

```
.\Rscript.exe -e $code
```

### Question

Is there a way to invoke Rscript by starting the process and still being able to use code containing spaces within the `$code`-Variable?

I want to invoke it via `Start-Process` in order not to block the Powershell script while executing the RScript.

Comment: You may try it the other way around ... `$code = 'print("With spaces");Sys.sleep(12)'`

Comment: Presumably Powershell is quoting the command line in a way that interferes with R's interpretation of it.  I'd check the docs for Powershell quoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`RScript.exe` is a *console* application, and the best way to invoke such applications - as in any shell - is by *direct* invocation** - no need for [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) for more information):

```
$code = "print('With spaces');Sys.sleep(12)"
.\Rscript.exe -e $code
```

- PowerShell will automatically handle double-quoting of the `$code` value *on demand*, based on whether the value contains spaces or note.
- As an aside (not required here): *situationally*, `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) is required for direct invocation, namely if the executable name or path is *quoted* and/or contains *variable references* (e.g. `& $rscriptPath ...` or `& 'C:\path to\RScript.exe' ...`)

**Caveat**: While there's no problem in this particular case, even with such direct invocation, **up to at least PowerShell 7.1, problems can arise with arguments that have *embedded* `"` characters and with *empty-string* arguments** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63627261/45375) for more information.

---

If you were to use `Start-Process` (not advisable here), you'd additionally have to:

- pass `-Wait` to ensure *synchronous* execution - but note that you wouldn't be able to (directly) capture *output* from the invocation in PowerShell.
- pass *all* arguments as a *single string* to `-ArgumentList` using *embedded (escaped) double-quoting* around your `$code` variable.

```
# Not advisable, but works in principle.
Start-Process -Wait .\Rscript.exe -ArgumentList "-e `"$code`""
```

While in an ideal world passing the arguments *individually* to `-AgumentList` - as you've tried - is undoubtedly preferable (or should at least work too), a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately makes it better to encode all arguments in a *single string*, as shown - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375) for more information.