# Run R silently from command line, export results to JSON

Tags: json, r, node.js

How might I call an R script from the shell (e.g. from Node.js exec) and export results as JSON (e.g. back to Node.js)?

The R code below basically works.  It reads data, fits a model, converts the parameter estimates to JSON, and prints them to stdout:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --quiet --slave
install.packages("cut", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/");
install.packages("Hmisc", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/");
install.packages("rjson", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/");
library(rjson)
library(reshape2);

data = read.csv("/data/records.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",");
mylogit <- glm( y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=data, family="binomial");
params <- melt(mylogit$coefficients);
json <- toJSON(params);
json
```

Here's how I'd like to call it from Node...

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('./model.R', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
   var params = JSON.parse(stdout);  // FAIL! Too much junk in stdout       
});
```

Except the R process won't stop printing to stdout.  I've tried `--quiet --slave --silent` which all help a little but not enough.  Here's what's sent to stdout:

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/tq/frvmq0kx4m1gydw26pcxgm7w0000gn/T//Rtmpyk7GmN/downloaded_packages

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/tq/frvmq0kx4m1gydw26pcxgm7w0000gn/T//Rtmpyk7GmN/downloaded_packages
[1] "{\"value\":[4.04458733165933,0.253895751245782,-0.1142272181932,0.153106007464742,-0.00289013062471735,-0.00282580664375527,0.0970325223603164,-0.0906967639834928,0.117150317941983,0.046131890754108,6.48538603593323e-06,6.70646151749708e-06,-0.221173770066275,-0.232262366060079,0.163331098409235]}"
```

[What's the best way to use R scripts on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750786/whats-the-best-way-to-use-r-scripts-on-the-command-line)

Running `R --silent --slave CMD BATCH model.R` per the post below still results in a lot of extraneous text printed to `model.Rout`:

[Run R script from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those options only stop R's own system messages from printing, they won't stop another R function doing some printing. Otherwise you'll stop your last line from printing and you won't get your json to stdout!

Those messages are coming from `install.packages`, so try:

```
 install.packages(-whatever-, quiet=TRUE)
```

which claims to reduce the amount of output. If it reduces it to zero, job done.

If not, then you can redirect stdout with `sink`, or run things inside `capture.output`.

Comment: Aha, that's it!  Last minor, is there a way to suppress the leading "`[1] `" as in `[1] "{\"value\":[4.04458733165933,...`

Comment: That's the label telling you its a length-1 vector, and that comes from the default print that happens when you name something on the command line. If you `cat(json)` instead it will print the raw string with no labels. Also, it won't escape the quotes which might be what you want anyway...