# Running R commands using a bash script

Tags: r, command

I have the  commands below that I use to make plots in R. The main text file is cross_correlation.csv.

How can I put it in bash script so that when I launch it on the terminal, the R commands will  perform their jobs and finish (like all other shell scripts).

```
cross_correlation <- read.table(file.choose(), header=F, sep="\t")

barplot(cross_correlation$V3)
dev.copy(png,"cc.png",width=8,height=6,units="in",res=100)
dev.off()

hist(cross_correlation$V3, breaks=15, prob=T)
dev.copy(png,"hist_cc.png",width=8,height=6,units="in",res=100)
dev.off()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run R script from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line)

Comment: I was about to suggest `R CMD BATCH script.r`, so in my opinion it's a dupe.

Comment: Something like an equivalent to `python -c '<commands>'` would be nice without having to create a script first.

Answer (score 10):

If you have R installed, you should also have the program `Rscript` installed, which can be used to run R scripts:

```
Rscript myscript.r
```

So you can put this line in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Rscript myscript1.r
Rscript myscript2.r
# other bash commands
```

This is usually the easiest way to run R scripts inside bash scripts.

If you want to make the script executable so you can run it by typing `./myscript.r`, you need to find out where your `Rscript` is installed by typing:

```
which Rscript
# /usr/bin/Rscript
```

Then your `myscript.r` will look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

cross_correlation <- read.table(file.choose(), header=F, sep="\t")

barplot(cross_correlation$V3)
dev.copy(png,"cc.png",width=8,height=6,units="in",res=100)
dev.off()

hist(cross_correlation$V3, breaks=15, prob=T)

dev.copy(png,"hist_cc.png",width=8,height=6,units="in",res=100)
dev.off()
```

This method is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750786/whats-the-best-way-to-use-r-scripts-on-the-command-line), which might also give you some ideas.

Comment: You can also use [`#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` as the shebang line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script).

Comment: Getting this error./runr.sh 
Error: unexpected symbol in "        cross_correlation <- read.table(file.choose(), header=F, sep="\t")    cross_correlation.csv"
Execution halted
./runr.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./runr.sh: line 12: ` cross_correlation <- read.table(file.choose(), header=F, sep="\t")'

Comment: Getting wrong @ dwcoder -
My 'myscript.r' is
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
cross_correlation <- read.table(file.choose(), header=F, sep="\t")   cross_correlation.csv
barplot(cross_correlation$V3)
dev.copy(png,"cc.png",width=8,height=6,units="in",res=100)
dev.off()

hist(cross_correlation$V3, breaks=15, prob=T)

dev.copy(png,"hist_cc.png",width=8,height=6,units="in",res=100)
dev.off()