# Pass output of R script to bash script

Tags: r, bash

I would like to pass the output of my R file to a bash script.
The output of the R script being the title of a video: *"Title of Video"*

And my bash script being simply:

```
youtube-dl title_of_video.avi  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w82a1FTere5o88
```

Ideally I would like the output of the video being "Title of Video".avi

I know I can use Rscript to launch an R script with a bash command but I don't think Rscript can help me here.

Answer (score 5):

In bash you can call a command and use its output further via the `$(my_command)` syntax.

Make sure your script only outputs the title.

E.g.

```
# in getTitle.R
cat('This is my title')   # note, print would have resulted in an extra "[1]"
```

```
# in your bash script:
youtube-dl $(Rscript getTitle.R) http://blablabla
```

---

If you want to pass arguments to your R script as well, do so inside the $() syntax; if you want to pass those arguments to your *bash* script, and delegate them to the R script to handle them, you can use the special bash variables `$1` (denote the 1st argument, etc), or `$*` to denote all arguments passed to the bash script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
youtube-dl $(Rscript getTitle.R $1) http://blablablabla
```

(this assumes that getTitle.R does something to those arguments internally via `commandArgs` etc to produce the wanted title output)

Answer (score 0):

You can call Rscript in bash script and you might assign the output of the R script to a variable in bash script. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201561/running-r-commands-using-a-bash-script). After that you can execute

```
youtube-dl $outputFromRScript  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w82a1FTere5o88
```