# executing file contents as commands under R from Linux terminal

Tags: r, linux, file, terminal, command

I've written a text file containing script for R. I've gotten it to run under Windows from a .bat file running a .txt file under R with CMD BATCH.

I'm trying to replicate that (minus the clickability) in the Terminal

I've  changed the permissions for program execution, I've set the file  to have the shebang, and have tried rewriting for it a few different programmes such as

```
#!/usr/bin/R

library(rvest)

library(plyr)
```

which returns an error "Syntax error near unexpected symbol 'rvest'

and

```
#!/home/robert/Téléchargements/R-3.2.3/src/unix/Rscript.c

library(rvest)

library(plyr)
```

which also returns an error "Syntax error near unexpected symbol 'rvest'

Separately, on both of these I changed the file extension from nothing to .R

In one case it gave the same error, in the other it started a session of R but didn't execute the commands.

I realise it's a messy question, but I'm having difficulty getting these ducks in a row.

Comment: What is the code used in terminal?

Comment: Alternately, /home/robert/R/scraper1                                                    and            /home/robert/R/scraper1.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, this was what worked:

```
R < /home/robert/R/scraper1.R --no-save
```

But here's the rest of my answer in case that doesn't work for someone else:

---

I'm not sure if you've seen any of these, but here's some stuff to try:

### Dupe?

*The top answer from [a very similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750786/whats-the-best-way-to-use-r-scripts-on-the-command-line): I'm going to assume you googled your question before posting it, so I'm sure you've already seen this, but it's not referenced in your question, so here it is [[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/969680/1152809)]:*

Content of script.r:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

cat("Hello")
```

Invocation from command line:

```
./script.r
```

---

### ?Rscript

*[`?Rscript`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html) allows you to run R scripts in a Unix-esque system [[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18306454/1152809)]:*

```
    ## example #! script for a Unix-alike

    #! /path/to/Rscript --vanilla --default-packages=utils
    args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
    res <- try(install.packages(args))
    if(inherits(res, "try-error")) q(status=1) else q()
```

---

### Batch

*Here's something from an old R mail pipe [[Source](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-October/040737.html)]:*

1. Place the line: `R --vanilla < foo.txt  foo.results` into a file named **foo.batch**.  No other text should be in the file.
2. Make this file executable via `chmod 755 foo.batch`
3. At the command line try `at -f foo.batch now` or perhaps, `batch -f foo.batch`.
4. If this does not work, ask your system administrator how to set up a batch process.

The advantage of the batch process is **1.** you need not be logged in, **2.**
your job will take a lower priority than interactive jobs.

---

### R -e

*Loading two libraries and running an R command [[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38314048/1152809)]*

```
R -e 'library("rmarkdown");library("knitr");rmarkdown::render("NormalDevconJuly.Rmd")'

R -e 'library("markdown");rpubsUpload("normalDev","NormalDevconJuly.html")'
```

---

### Other

- `R < scriptname.R --no-save` [[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30647797/1152809)]
- `$ source("scriptname.R")` [[Source](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-September/140676.html)]

Comment: Your answer's given me a couple of things to test, I'll play around it with it for a few hours. Fingers-crossed!

Comment: R < /home/robert/R/scraper1.R --no-save          for the win! Thank you!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear.

Comment: Also, just fyi, if you put tick marks around in-line code, it will be easier to decipher it from the rest of your text: `\`this\`` will look like `this`. It's not a quote, but the tick mark underneath the tilde (~), typically the key under Esc.