# crontab: tmp/tmp.X: Operation not permitted in RStudio using `cronR` on Mac OSX Mojave

Tags: r, macos, cron

I want to schedule an `R` script to run regularly. The most obvious attempt I found when googling is using the `cronR` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cronR/README.html) and the RStudio Add-In that comes with it.

After creating a dummy script containing only `cat("Hello World")` I opened the Add-In and created the job. When trying to start the job I ended up with the error message

> crontab: tmp/tmp.X: Operation not permitted

This led me to the question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/954586/osx-mojave-crontab-tmp-tmp-x-operation-not-permitted). I granted `Terminal` and `cron` full Disk access. The problem remained.

---

Edit after comment by @Maylo:

I tried adding the job manually using `crontab -e`. The line I added was:

> 0 * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /Users/me/Documents/R/test.R

After quitting `crontab -e` with `:wq` I got the following message on my terminal:

```
crontab: no crontab for me - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab
crontab: tmp/tmp.37904: Operation not permitted
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.Jw9DPv2aBd
```

---

*What else may cause this error message / problem?*

*Are there any other solutions to run a script regularly? (say every hour)*

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: how about just adding the cronjob directly? does this still give you trouble? For example `0 * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /path/to/your/R/script` or wherever Rscript is installed on mac? Add the aforementioned line to `crontab -e`

Comment: @Maylo: Thx for your comment. I added this line and ended up with the same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use batch scripts?

Comment: @Christoph What do you mean by 'batch scripts'? Can you make an example?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18306362/5784831) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750786/5784831). I don't use MACOS...

Comment: @Christoph That's what I do. The part that does not work is not running the script, but scheduling it.. Thx anyway

Comment: I'm having the same issue as described in the part two. Maybe it started after a `brew update`, but that might be unrelated. Did you figure it out by chance?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when trying to set one of my bash scripts to run every night.

As soon as I exited nano editor, it gave me the same error message and could not install new cron.

Problem was that I was using MacOSX ssh from remote and so this happened. So, to solve this you need to go into actual MacOSX machine locally on desktop without remote. Open terminal and try to install new cron, it will ask for a special permission (I am using MacOSX Sonoma), the permission is totally different than the full disk access as mentioned everywhere on Google. it says something like "Control". After you allow it, you will be able to edit cron even via remote.